# It's supposed to be an infinite loop, but it stops after execv

Tags: c, loops, execv

I'm developing a shell command in C, and I have a problem when using the command execv. I have a do while(1) in the main, so it should be an infinite loop, but if i introduce /bin/ls as the command, the prompt shows the files and folders and then it stops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 256
#define DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH  256
#define MAX_PARAMETERS  16


void  initParams(char  ***  params);
void  read_command(char  *** params);
void  freeParams(char  ***  params);
void type_prompt();
int comprobarSalir(char ***cadena);

int main(){

    int salir = 0;

    do{


    char ** params;



    type_prompt();

    fflush(stdout);
    initParams (& params);
    read_command (& params);
    salir = comprobarSalir(& params);

    if(comprobarSalir(&params)==0){

        if(execv(params[0],  params) ==  -1){
            printf("%s,%s",params[0],params[1]);
            printf("Error  al  ejecutar  el  comando ' %s':  %s\n", params [0],  strerror(errno));
            freeParams (& params);
        }

    }


    }while(1);


}


void  read_command(char  *** args) {
    char  input [256], *substr;
    int n = 0;
    fgets(input , sizeof(input), stdin);
    input[strlen(input) -1] = '\0';
    substr = strtok(input , " ");
    if (substr  != NULL)
        memcpy ((* args)[n], substr , strlen(substr));
    else
        (*args)[n] = NULL;
        n++;
    while ((* args)[n-1] != NULL) {
        substr = strtok(NULL , " ");
        if (substr  != NULL)
            memcpy ((* args)[n], substr , strlen(substr));
        else
            (*args)[n] = NULL;
            n++;
    }
}

void  freeParams(char  *** params){
    int i;
    char ** parameter;
    for (i=0; i<MAX_PARAMETERS; i++) {
        parameter = ((* params) +i);
        if (* parameter  != NULL) free(* parameter);
    }
    free(* params);
    *params = NULL;
}


void  initParams(char  *** params) {
    int i, j;
    char ** parameter;
    *params = (char **) malloc(sizeof(parameter) * MAX_PARAMETERS);
    for (i = 0; i<MAX_PARAMETERS; i++) {
        parameter = (* params) + i;
        *parameter = (char*) malloc(DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
        for (j = 0; j<DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH; j++)  *((* parameter)+j) = '\0';
    }
}

void type_prompt(){
    char cwd[MAX_LENGTH];
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    printf("%s$ ",cwd);
}

int comprobarSalir(char ***cadena){

    int salir = 0;
    char* exit = "exit";

    if(***cadena==*exit){
        salir = 1231;
    }

    return salir;
}
```

Comment: `void  read_command(char  *** args) {` ... I like it!!! BTW: You do seem to like void functions, don't you?

Comment: Please format your code properly before posting it here. One program that does this is `indent`.

Comment: Sorry roland, i'm a newbie. Next time i'll follow your tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execv` replaces the process that invokes it with a different program.

Since the current process is now running a different program (`ls`), of course its loop will no longer continue.

---

If you want a process to continue to run after calling `execv`, then you need to use `fork()` to create a child process; check whether you're the parent or the child, and call `execv` only in the child. At that point, if you want the parent to wait for the copy of `ls` to finish, you can use `wait()` in the parent to do so, and determine whether the child succeeded or failed.

Comment: So... it's supossed to be a shell command. How can i go back to the main program and read commands while the input is "exit"

Comment: This answer, as edited, tells you how to do that already: You *don't* use `execv` directly in the main process (since using it exits your program); instead you use `fork()` to create a copy of yourself, and `execv()` only in the copy, then `wait()`ing to let the copy execute and find out whether it succeeded.